# Excel - put login times into neat hours

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, macros

I have this info in an excel spreadsheet ..
representing the amount of time spent logged in to a computer..

```
logins  time of day    amount of time logged in (h:mm)
------  -----------    -------------------------------
login      03:21        
logout     05:03       1:42
login      05:47    
logout     06:26       0:39
```

And i want to turn it into this ..

```
time of day     amount of time logged in (mins)
-------------   -------------------------------
03:00 - 04:00    39
04:00 - 05:00    60
05:00 - 06:00    16
06:00 - 07:00    26
```

It seems very complicated and I'm getting tied up in knots with excel formulas .. if anyone knows a formula that would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way of doing this, not very elegant may be someone has a shorter method of doing this and will come up after seeing this ugly one, perhaps here is my attempt, exclusively works with `MS365 Version Of Excel`:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>E2</kbd>

```
=LET(
     _Data, A2:B5,
     _First, TAKE(_Data,1,-1),
     _Adjustments, IF(TAKE(_Data,1,1)="Logout",
                   VSTACK(_First,MROUND(_First,"1:00"),DROP(_Data,1,1)),
                   DROP(_Data,,1)),
     _H2M, 1440,
     _TFormat, "hh:mm",
     _TimeFrame, WRAPROWS(UNIQUE(_Adjustments,,1),2,CEILING(MAX(_Adjustments),"1:00:00"))*_H2M,
     _TSequence, TOCOL(DROP(REDUCE("",SEQUENCE(ROWS(_TimeFrame)),LAMBDA(_x,_y, 
                 LET(_z,INDEX(_TimeFrame,_y,1),_w,INDEX(_TimeFrame,_y,2),
                 VSTACK(_x,SEQUENCE(,_w-_z,_z))))),1)/_H2M,2),
     _Uniq, UNIQUE(HOUR(_TSequence))/24,
     HSTACK(TEXT(_Uniq,_TFormat)&" - "&TEXT(_Uniq+1/24,_TFormat),
            TOCOL(BYCOL(LOOKUP(_TSequence,_Uniq)*24=TOROW(_Uniq*24),LAMBDA(_b,SUM(--_b))))))
```

---

Test Case 1:

[image]

---

Test Case 2:

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/152189/discussion-on-answer-by-mayukh-bhattacharya-excel-put-login-times-into-neat-ho); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: Thanks Mayukh, yes you are right that an uneven number of logins and logouts causes a CALC! error e.g. starting with a logout .. but .. even if that is corrected and the range is from a login to a logout with an even number of both in-between, duplicate entries still cause the formula to fail. .. i could get the login time format in hh:mm:ss and then there wouldn't be any duplicates because even the shortest login is at least one second .. but i don't know how to amend the formula to include 'ss'.

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya You only need 20 rep to [Privileges - Talk in chat - Super User](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/chat)

Comment: @Andyjmr fixed now, but don't remove duplicates and keep as is without sorted, it will work!